What is the shortest distance between two moving objects, and at what time?
An object $A$ is moving $10\ \mathrm{km/h}$ North while an object $B$ is moving $5\ \mathrm{km/h}$ East. Object $B$ starts $1\ \mathrm{km}$ North of object $A$. At $t = 0$ seconds, $A=(0,0)$ and $B=(0,1)$.
At what time are the two objects closest? What is the distance between them at this time?
I've made vector functions so that $A=(0,tv_a)$ and $B=(tv_b,1)$. With the triangle inequality $|d|<=|a+b|$ the distance should be the shortest when they are not perpendicular. I set them equal to each other and made $v_a$ become $2v_b$.
$2v_bt=tv_b+1$
$v_b=1$
But one magnitude of objectB's velocity would make both objects 5km away from (0,1) have a distance of $5 \sqrt{2}$ km. That is even further than when they started.

HINT
The positions of the moving bodies can be expressed as follows:
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
s_{A}(t) = A_{0} + tv_{A}\\\\
s_{B}(t) = B_{0} + tv_{B}
\end{cases} & \Longleftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
s_{A}(t) = (0, 10t)\\\\
s_{B}(t) = (5t, 1) 
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
Consequently, $\mathrm{d}_{AB}(t) = \sqrt{25t^{2} + (10t - 1)^{2}} = \sqrt{125t^{2} - 20t + 1}$.
Given that $t\geq 0$, can you differentiate the function $\mathrm{d}_{AB}(t)$ and proceed from here?

There are two major ways to solve such problems one using calculus and another using, relative motion, I will write down both of the solution for you,
Method 1
We can write down the position of A from $t = 0$, to some arbitrary time $t $as follows
$$(0, 10t)$$
Similarly we can also write down the position of B as follows from $t = 0$, to some arbitrary time $t$ as follows
$$(5t, 1)$$
The distance between them can be written down as follows(using the distance formula in coordinate geometry),
$$d = \sqrt{25t^2 + (10t - 1)^2}$$
$$d^2 = 25t^2 + (10t - 1)^2$$
Now we just have to differentiate $d^2$ with respect to $t$ and that gives us the time when they are closest and, we can also find the distance by plugging back the time into the equation.
Method 2
Another way of solving this problem which uses a bit of relative motion from physics is as follows,
In the frame of reference of B the velocity of A is $10\hat{j} - 5\hat{i}$,
we can easily see that in the frame of reference of B, A will be moving in a straight line, the distance between them will be the shortest when A is at the perpendicular from B to that line
This, point can be found using coordinate geometry and hence we find when the distance is minimum and what it is!

I might be misunderstanding but if object A and B are perpendicular, the distance should be 0.5 km. However if both objects travel for 4.5 minutes, I calculated there distance to be 0.45 km. Doesn't that mean they are not the closest when they are at the same y-coordinate?

The distance you calculated was in the frame of reference of B, transform it into the frame of reference of the lab.
